# Lipschitz solutions to linear complementarity problems (LCP)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

For $q\in\mathbb{R}^n$, define the set:
$$S_M(q)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n|y\ge 0,q+My\ge 0, y^\top (q+My)=0\}.$$
This is the set of solutions to the LCP $(q,M)$.

We say $S_M(\cdot)$ is Lipschitz if there exists $L$ such that for all $q_1,q_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$S_M(q_1)\subseteq S_M(q_2)+L \|q_1-q_2\|_2 B,$$
where $B$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

[Murthy, Parthasarathy, and Sriparna (1998)](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479896313814) gives a conjecture of the class of $M$ for which $S_M$ is Lipschitz. Has this been proved subsequently? Are there any other characterizations of these "Lipschitzian" $M$ matrices?

Additionally, I am interested in conditions on $M$ under which there exists a Lipschitz function $s_M:\{q\in\mathbb{R}^n|S_M(q)\ne\emptyset\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ with $s_M(q)\in S_M(q)$ for all $q\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I have not seen this discussed in the literature. Are there results on this problem?

Comment: Not until 2020 according to the recent survey written by one of the authors:  https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10479-018-2939-3.pdf

Comment: @foxell Are you aware of any work on the second question, about Lipschitz selections?

Comment: Yes. This is a very classical question in variational analysis (usually S_M is the generalized derivative or Jacobian). A special case is that when S_M is polyhedral, then such a selection always exists, which can be found in Rockafellar's book "Implicit function and solution mappings" (Theorem 3D.1). (I remember that some recent nonsmooth optimization paper has more detailed discussion). For more general discussion outside optimization community (for general metric space or Banach space), the next two papers are good: "Lipschitz selections of set-valued mappings and Helly’s theorem"

Comment: And "THE WHITNEY EXTENSION PROBLEM AND LIPSCHITZ
SELECTIONS OF SET-VALUED MAPPINGS IN JET-SPACES".

Comment: Oh, if you mean specialized on the LCP problem, then I do not know exactly. But I remember that Boris Mordukhovich recently published a series of works near this direction. I didn't check them carefully because they are too long.

Comment: @foxell 3D.1 of the Rockafellar book just establishes that it is outer Lipschitz continuous. Why does this imply the existence of a Lipschitz selection?

Comment: @foxell For example, consider the multifunction $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $S(q)=-1$ for $q<0$, $S(q)=1$ for $q>0$ and $S(q)=[-1,1]$ for $q=0$. This is outer Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ (with arbitrarily small modulus), but it does not possess a Lipschitz selection on $\mathbb{R}$.